# iOS Swift 5: How to execute a js file in a WKWebView?

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, xcode, wkwebview

How can i execute **script.js** in **WKWebView**? I know about  `webView.evaluateJavaScript` but i can't figure out how to evaluate my script.js file, i already tried some solutions i found on stackoverflow by other users but nothing works can anybody help me with this? i'm losing my mind:(

This is what i tried:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
                       webView.evaluateJavaScript("script.js", completionHandler: nil)
               }
```

Comment: Take data from your file as a string and then call  `webView.evaluateJavaScript(string, completionHandler: nil)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just trying to run some javascript but you don't actually want to connect it to an HTML document then you should be using [JavaScriptCore](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/javascriptcore) rather than WKWebview.

```
import JavaScriptCore

let context = JSContext()

guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "script", ofType: "js"),
  let script = try? String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: .utf8) else {
    fatalError("cannot load script")
}

let jsResult = context?.evaluateScript(script)
print(jsResult)
```